# Change css value based on active li value in slider glider js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Wanting to change css html background image based on active glider js li value

here is the css

```
html { 
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496518908709-02b67989c265?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  height: 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I am using Glider.js so when the current slide is in frame the a class glide__slide--active is added to the

```
<div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
    <ul class="glide__slides">
      <li class="glide__slide" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage1.jpg">01</li>
      <li class="glide__slide glide__slide--active" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage2.jpg" >02</li>
      <li class="glide__slide" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage3.jpg">03</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so change the url of the background image using jquery with value of data-image-value

Answer (score 0):

According to the [events section of the glidejs documentation](https://glidejs.com/docs/events/) you can listen for the transitions to end like:

```
glide.on('move.after', function(event) {
    // store the background in a variable
    var newBG = $('.glide__slide--active').attr('data-image-value');
    // apply the background image to the element (html or body...whatever you're using)
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + newBG + ')');
});
```

Without seeing a reproducible example, thats about the best I can do for you. More code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [GlideJS Event API](https://glidejs.com/docs/events/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var glide = new Glide('.glide')

  // Listen to the move.after event (Called right after movement transition ends.)
  glide.on('move.after', function() {
    // Get the active slide and store it's data-image 
    const imageSrc = $('.glide__slide--active').attr('image');

    // Set the background
    $('html').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
  })

  glide.mount()
});
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496518908709-02b67989c265?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="glide">
  <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
    <ul class="glide__slides">
      <li class="glide__slide" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage1.jpg">01</li>
      <li class="glide__slide glide__slide--active" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage2.jpg">02</li>
      <li class="glide__slide" data-image-value="https://bob.com/image/bigimage3.jpg">03</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```